# Can a former US President settle in a hostile country?

Tags: united-states, president

While I was searching about what are the restrictions on former US  Presidents concerning the United States' own security and its classified information. I found nothing more than a Wikipedia page  [Former Presidents Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Former_Presidents_Act) .
But that page is not much use for what I am interested in.

I would especially like to know: **can an ex-president of the United States settle in another country with which the current US relations are  not very good or tense, or which is/was hostile towards the US, if he wishes to?**

Comment: Yes.  He's as free as any other American.  Also note, living in another country isn't the same as changing one's citizenship or nationality.  The bigger question is, if he did, would he still be entitled to secret service protection, and if so, what might that hosting country think about that!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, same as any other citizen.

It would seem unlikey that a "hostile" country would grant a visa, but if they did, then there is nothing in law or the constitution to prevent a former President from leaving the USA.

It would raise some eyebrows politically.  The CIA would be quite concerned. If it was thought the ex-President was giving state secrets, then I wouldn't be too surprised if there was some kind of CIA black-ops. But the USA doesn't have exit visas. It allows citizens and former citizens to take up residence abroad. There are no special laws for the President.

The President might lose many of the benefits, such as pension or secret service protection.

It has never happened.  No President has retired even to a friendly country, though there has been [talk of Trump moving to Scotland](https://www.thenational.scot/news/18853454.us-election-donald-trump-set-come-scotland-losing-presidency/) to spend more time with his golf clubs.  (Is Scotland hostile to the USA? It is certainly hostile to Trump)

Comment: That is one of the "additional benefits".  It exists because there are nutters out there who think that murdering an ex-president is a good thing to do.

Comment: On the other hand, one could assume a "hostile" country would be more than willing to issue a visa (perhaps after the initial raised eyebrows), even if only to reap PR benefits ("See, our country is so great even US Presidents move here to retire!"), or just for the chance of getting some useful intel or getting said ex-President to work for them.

Comment: @JamesK Has that ever happened?  There have of course been a number of assassination attempts (some successful) of *sitting* presidents, but I haven't heard of any situations where there was an attempt on the life of any president after leaving office.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: That can mean two things: a) there have been no attempts or b) the Secret Service protection is working.

Comment: But Scotland is in the UK, which has an extradition treaty with the US, so Trump might prefer a different country.

Comment: "Is Scotland hostile to the USA? It is certainly hostile to Trump" - some very loud people do not necessarily speak for the whole country ....

Comment: One could certainly entertain the possibility of a certain ex-President, faced with a multitude of criminal charges and civil suits, seeking asylum in Russia.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: For example, in 2018, [someone tried to mail a pipe bomb to Obama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_2018_United_States_mail_bombing_attempts) (and to several other people as well). The Secret Service intercepted it.

Comment: @Kevin Fair point - I forgot about that, even though the pipe bombs in question were reportedly so poorly made they would never have exploded even if they hadn't been caught.  Still, there've been *far* more (at least reported) attempts on sitting presidents, who generally have even better protection, and yet some have succeeded, so I'm guessing there's just less motive to go after someone who's not in office any more.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - In 1993 Iraq tried to assassinate former president George W. Bush via a car bomb during a visit to Kuwait.  Kuwaiti authorities foiled the attempt. Bill Clinton later retaliated with a missile strike. See https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/clinton-punishes-iraq-for-plot-to-kill-bush, https://oig.justice.gov/sites/default/files/archive/special/9704a/05bush2.htm, https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/inatl/longterm/iraq/timeline/062793.htm. https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/DOC_0000756374.pdf.

Comment: You probably mean George H.W. Bush, ie Bush senior, not George W. (ie Bush Junior)

Comment: @JamesK - yes that's correct.  I forgot the `H.`.

Comment: @jamesqf My fearless prediction is that said ex-president will pick the UAE as his future residence.

Comment: @Don Hosek: Doubt it.  While the US doesn't have a formal extradition treaty with the UAE, it does have a rather significant military presence there, and AFAIK no particular reason to do that particular ex-President any favors.  Russia, or at least its current ruler, has every reason, including repayment of favors.

Comment: "...same as any other citizen..." most citizens don't have a secret service contingent with them at all times. Since you are so certain that "a former US President (can) settle in a hostile country" can you address the protection of the former president and the sensitive knowledge they have by the US. Secret Service? Is shedding that protection a premise here? Or would there be no problem with 24/7 protection at home and while traveling? With so much concern over answers that are "primarily opinion-based" it would be great if some facts can be cited and sourced here related to practicalities.